# Receive Files in Android using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, smack, asmack

I am trying to receive a file using the asmack jar. I am able to receive text  on my android device with no problem but  when I set up the file transfer I get an error saying that "does not support file transfers". The listener is never being called...  I set up my listener like this:

```
if (m_connection != null)
        {

            ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            if (sdm == null)
            {
                sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
                sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
                sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
            }

            // new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
            FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
            FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(m_connection);
            manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
                public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request)
                {

                    Log.i("InstallerActivity", "Got new File!!!");
```

EDIT: Added these to make it work:

```
pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("open", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new IBBProviders.Open());
    pm.addIQProvider("close", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new IBBProviders.Close());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new IBBProviders.Data());
    pm.addIQProvider("open", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new OpenIQProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("close", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new CloseIQProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());
```

Comment: I am already using this solution but still I am facing this problem. Can you help in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add `IQProvider` feature for `FileTransfer`?

```
// //File transfer
    pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
            new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("open", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
            new OpenIQProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("close", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
            new CloseIQProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
            new DataPacketProvider());
```

Here is very useful file transfer tutorial using asmack. [File transfer in android with asmack and Openfire](http://harryjoy.com/2012/08/18/file-transfer-in-android-with-asmack-and-openfire/)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any doucumentation on this? I added all of the ones above. Is this correct what is the difference between them?

Comment: @Jul I am already using this solution but still I am facing this problem. Can you help in solving this problem?

Comment: @Jul I have used your solution still facing the same problem. Can you see over this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28271210/4358880)